# what happens in IIS or behind code when getting a request from web browser?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services, iis

I'm trying to make an excel download function.
I created a webservice that serializes string type of xml parameters.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string DATACRUD(string XmlParms)
{
    XmlParms = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(XmlParms);
.
.
.
.
}
```

I call this through Ajax and putting location.href value from Javascript.

This has worked fine in both ways, until it reaches maxUrl and maxQueryString configured in web.config.

```
<requestLimits maxUrl="4096" maxQueryString="4096" />
```

and `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="300000" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2097151" />`

the causing url looks like this.

```
localhost:/MyWebservice.asmx/DATACRUD?XmlParms={%27service%27:%27M_CUST%27,%27method%27:%27EXCEL%27,%27type%27:%27XLS%27,%27_order%27:%27M_CUST_NO%20DESC%27,%27_sort%27:%27%27,%27USITE%27:%2712%27,%27UID%27:%271000059%27,%27UKEY%27:%27F778BFB5-9920-4197-878C-8BAB6B5CF457%27,%27key%27:%270%27,%27MENUID%27:%271001%27,%27STEPMENU%27:%27%27,%27ACTIONNAME%27:%27xls%EB%8B%A4%EC%9A%B4%27,%27xlsType%27:%27report%27,%27xlsService%27:%27M_CUST%27,%27xlsMethod%27:%27undefined%27,%27dispCols%27:%27{%22dispCols%22%20:[{%20colNo:%20%220%22,%20label:%20%22%EB%B2%88%ED%98%B8%22,%20field:%20%22M_CUST_NO%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%221%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%95%84%EC%9D%B4%EB%94%94%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%222%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%9D%B4%EB%A6%84%22,%20field:%20%22CUST_NAME%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%223%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%95%BD%EA%B5%AD%EB%AA%85%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%224%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%9A%8C%EC%9B%90%EA%B7%B8%EB%A3%B9%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%225%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%82%AC%EC%97%85%EC%9E%90%EB%B2%88%ED%98%B8%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%226%22,%20label:%20%22%EA%B0%80%EC%9E%85%EA%B2%BD%EB%A1%9C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%227%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%B6%94%EC%B2%9C%EC%9D%B8%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%228%22,%20label:%20%22ETC%EC%BD%94%EB%93%9C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%229%22,%20label:%20%22ETC%EB%8B%B4%EB%8B%B9MM%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2210%22,%20label:%20%22ETC%EC%82%AC%EB%AC%B4%EC%86%8C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2211%22,%20label:%20%22OTC%EC%BD%94%EB%93%9C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2212%22,%20label:%20%22OTC%EB%8B%B4%EB%8B%B9MM%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2213%22,%20label:%20%22OTC%EC%82%AC%EB%AC%B4%EC%86%8C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2214%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%8F%AC%EC%82%AC%EC%BD%94%EB%93%9C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2215%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%8F%AC%EC%82%AC%EB%8B%B4%EB%8B%B9MM%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2216%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%8F%AC%EC%82%AC%EC%82%AC%EB%AC%B4%EC%86%8C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2217%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%95%BD%EA%B5%AD%EC%A0%84%ED%99%94%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2218%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%9C%B4%EB%8C%80%ED%8F%B0%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2219%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%9A%8C%EC%9B%90%EC%83%81%ED%83%9C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2220%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%9A%8C%EC%9B%90%EA%B0%80%EC%9E%85%EC%9D%BC%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2221%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%9A%8C%EC%9B%90%EC%8A%B9%EC%9D%B8%EC%9D%BC%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2222%22,%20label:%20%22%EA%B0%80%EC%9E%85%EA%B5%AC%EB%B6%84%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2223%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%95%BD%EA%B5%AD%EC%A3%BC%EC%86%8C%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2224%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%9D%B4%EB%A9%94%EC%9D%BC%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2225%22,%20label:%20%22%ED%8E%98%EC%97%85%EC%9D%BC%EC%9E%90%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20},{%20colNo:%20%2226%22,%20label:%20%22%EC%B5%9C%EC%A2%85%EB%A1%9C%EA%B7%B8%EC%9D%B8%EC%9D%BC%EC%9E%90%22,%20field:%20%22%22%20}]}%27,%27structureName%27:%27CST_CUSTOMER_TBL%27}
```

it's lengthy, I know.

At the first place, I got an `404.15 error`.
Then IIS suggested me to add the `requestLimits` and `httpRuntime` tags I mentioned above.

so I could pass the `404.15 error` successfully, but next, another trap was there.

```
    System.NotSupportedException: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.
   at: System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetDefaultIndexer(Type type, String memberInfo)
   at: System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.ImportTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean directReference)
   at: System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
   at: System.Xml.Serialization.ModelScope.GetTypeModel(Type type, Boolean directReference)
   at: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type type, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace)
   at: System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturn.GetInitializers(LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)
   at: System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.GetInitializers(LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)
   at: System.Web.Services.Protocols.MimeFormatter.GetInitializers(Type type, LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)
   at: System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at: System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at: System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

I don't know what to do in this phase.

I will try debug if this url successfully invokes the webservice, but before calling it, it throws this plain text error message.

what happens in IIS or behind code when getting the request from web browser ?

Comment: You probably need to use a "post", not a "get" for large data so the data doesn't have to all be in the URL.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes choosing post method will be the best option for this error and I hope I could do that way. But for some reasons, I have to do this way, expending the max url length and passing into those query string to the webservice, leaving the rest jobs to it. It's inevitable, very unfortunately..

Comment: Http has a hard limit on the number of characters that can be in a URI.